# What are the criteria for reviewing suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review

Two reviewers have reviewed my edit for this question

https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5816

The first approved, the second rejected because "[t]his edit simply rephrases the question in different words".

Well, yes! That was indeed the point of my edit and why I labeled it as copy-editing: to make the question more readable without changing what is being asked.

Now has there been some rule change to make copy-edits not welcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rejected it as such, mostly because, while it corrected a few unclear parts, the majority of it was simply rephrasing things that were already fine. For example,

> I was invited to a concert late night in a city called Faqra (located in north Lebanon - Middle East).

`>>>`

> I recently visited a city called Faqra (located in north Lebanon - Middle East)

I'm not sure why that needs to be changed. There were, however, plenty of things that needed to be fixed (and were). Looking at it again, I probably should have approved it because of that. My apologies for rejecting it and happy editing.